# How to isolate space delimited values that may contain a space?

Tags: php, regex, validation, delimiter

I have an input where a user will enter a class schedule in the following format

```
[time] [days] [room]
```

e.g:

```
7-8 am MWF ROOM1 | 7:30-9:30 am TTH Room2 | 11:30 am-12:30 pm MWF Room3)
```

So I tried exploding the input using space then get the last two values of the returned array and make the as `$room` and `$days`, then I subtracted the two in the original `$schedule` to get the remaining and make it my `$time`.

```
$sched = explode(" ", $schedule);
if(count($sched) <= 3){
    echo 'please check schedule format!';
}else{
   $room  = array_values(array_slice($sched, -1))[0];
   $days  = array_values(array_slice($sched, -2))[0];
   $times = str_replace($days." ".$room, "" ,$schedule);
}
```

using the code above I'm getting the result I want, but the problem is when the user does not put DAYS or ROOM the text adjusts so I'm not getting the right value.

For example this input value

```
11:30 am-12:30 pm mwf (no room)
```

I'm getting this result: `(room:mwf) (days:pm) (times:11:30 am-12:30 )`

Is there better way to this?

Comment: This is an interesting question.  It seems like you are possibly reinventing the wheel in terms of a problem that has been solved by command line program parsing.  PHP has a built-in and there are components like the symfony command component that has support libraries to handle parsing.  I also found this library that looks like it would be tailor made for your problem:  https://github.com/c9s/GetOptionKit

Comment: Obviously you would have to rethink your input in terms of parameters, so you would need the input to be either name=value or -param value, but the big advantage is that you could have optionals or support any order of parameters, where now, the smallest screw up would break your parsing.  Given the functionality in the library, you'd save a lot of time too, and the argument code would be clean and self documenting, as we'll as having a built-in help documentation feature.

Comment: As said, simplify your input data. It looks really easy to spoof that and cause a bug. To validate a date I'd use `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date)` and then check if `$date` is false. If it's, then the value doesn't match with the format mask or it's not right (e.g. 30th February)

Comment: @gview i tried installing the library but im having a hard time understanding the given examples. my bad though im new in using libraries

Comment: @mickmackusa values between the pipes are correct example. what im trying to say is how will i divide the values. TIME DAYS ROOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern will process the full string and spit out a multi-dimensional array.  How do you want to handle the results?

Test Code:  ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/91e324956d8a938e61e1c0b786fe52468e863e20))

```
//$sched='7-8 am MWF ROOM1 | 7:30-9:30 am TTH Room2 | 11:30 am-12:30 pm MWF Room3';
$sched='MWF ROOM1 | 7:30-9:30 am Room2 | 11:30 am-12:30 pm MWF';
//$sched='ROOM1 | 7:30-9:30 am | MWF | MTWTHFS';

if(preg_match_all('/(?:^|\| )([^|]*?m)? ?([MTWHFS]*) ?([Rr][Oo]{2}[Mm]\d+)?(?: |$)/',$sched,$out,PREG_SET_ORDER)){
    foreach($out as $a){
        if(empty($a[1])){
            echo "Missing/Invalid Time\n";
        }
        if(empty($a[2])){
            echo "Missing/Invalid Days\n";
        }
        if(empty($a[3])){
            echo "Missing/Invalid Room\n";
        }
        var_export(array_slice($a,1));
        echo"\n\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Missing/Invalid Time
array (
  0 => '',
  1 => 'MWF',
  2 => 'ROOM1',
)

Missing/Invalid Days
array (
  0 => '7:30-9:30 am',
  1 => '',
  2 => 'Room2',
)

Missing/Invalid Room
array (
  0 => '11:30 am-12:30 pm',
  1 => 'MWF',
)
```

Comment: @Raymond I can process the string using regex, but I am unsure how you want to handle the results.  Please explain so that I can fit my answer to your expectations.

Comment: i already have the regex for the pattern time days room e.g.  7:30 am-8:30 am MWF Room1. So the user can no longer enter missing time, day or room. The last thing i need is how to divide or separate the values time days and room in this example 7:30 am-8:30 am MWF Room1.

Comment: @Raymond Pattern: `(.*?m) ([MTWHFS]+) ([Rr][Oo]{2}[Mm]\d+)`  [Demo Link](https://regex101.com/r/QbikMy/1)

Comment: how will i explode it to store it in an array. The time, days and room

Comment: This is a pattern to be used with preg_match().  I can probably whack together another pattern for preg_split().  Do you know how to go with preg_match()? Or shall I code something up for you?

Comment: @Raymond  Here's a rather clever (and reliable) use of preg_split: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/96a3f59ab9cb1f3b9d2918cbb72e67738dc437b3